# How to delete Github Tags not assigned to a release?

Tags: git, github, github-api

In our GitHub repos we have a set of tags and a set of releases which are assigned to tags.

Now we would like to delete the tags not assigned to a release.

Any idea how to do this with git commands?

Thanks for a hint.

Best Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Github [ref API](https://developer.github.com/v3/git/refs/) & Github [releases API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/releases/#list-releases-for-a-repository) with [jq JSON parser](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) to :

- download all tag ref `/git/refs/tags`
- download all releases & extract tag name
- remove releases tag from tag ref list
- delete tags when you are ready

script :

```bash
REPO=remotestorage/remotestorage.js

TAG_LIST=$(curl -s "https://api.github.com/repos/$REPO/git/refs/tags?per_page=100" | \
    jq '[ .[] | .ref ]')

RELEASE_LIST=$(curl -s "https://api.github.com/repos/$REPO/releases?per_page=100" | \
    jq  '[ .[] | "refs/tags/" + .tag_name ]')

NOT_IN_RELEASE=$(echo $TAG_LIST | jq --argjson releases "$RELEASE_LIST" '. - $releases' | jq -r '.[]')

echo "$NOT_IN_RELEASE"

# when you are ready
# echo $NOT_IN_RELEASE | xargs git tag -d
```

Note that if you have more than 100 releases or tags, you will have to [traverse pagination](https://developer.github.com/v3/guides/traversing-with-pagination/)

---

With Github [Graphql API v4](https://developer.github.com/v4/), you can combine the 2 requests above into a single one. In [the explorer](https://developer.github.com/v4/explorer/) :

```json
{
  repository(owner: "remotestorage", name: "remotestorage.js") {
    releases(first: 100) {
      nodes {
        tag {
          name
        }
      }
    }
    refs(first: 100, refPrefix: "refs/tags/") {
      nodes {
        name
      }
    }
  }
}
```

script would be :

```bash
NOT_IN_RELEASE=$(curl -s -H "Authorization: bearer YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN" -d '
 {
   "query": "query { repository(owner: \"remotestorage\", name: \"remotestorage.js\") { releases(first: 100) { nodes { tag { name } } } refs(first: 100, refPrefix: \"refs/tags/\") {nodes { name } } } }"
 }
' https://api.github.com/graphql | \
    jq -r '.data.repository | [.refs.nodes[].name] - [.releases.nodes[].tag.name] | .[]')

echo "$NOT_IN_RELEASE"

# when you are ready
# echo $NOT_IN_RELEASE | xargs git tag -d
```